# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE flg=0x1 }

Tags: java, android, storage, android-developer-api, saf

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
```

I am trying to open  file directory in an android supported Interactive Flat panel name BENQ having android 11 . I try to open the file directory but this line of code gave me error

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE flg=0x1 }

Does any one know how to fix this or any alternative?

"Some have suggested it might be very likely related to the fact that some users have disabled the FILES app on their devices, since MOST PROBABLY the error is not occurring on all the devices models listed above, but for a subset"

above is the solution suggested by some but i can not find how to activate the files app , i am not able to do anything.

also if some can please tell how can i read data from usb device in android without SAF in android 11 or above it will be of great help.

Note - My code working on almost all devices but this is the special case but it important for me to fix it.

Comment: @blackapps I think it is needed as i am storing the treeUri after opening it once so the permission is needed i think .

Comment: Show me your manifest.xml

Comment: @Laxmikant 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

These are the permissions that i have added and rest is unchanged

Comment: @blackapps removing it didn't solve the problem

Comment: And dont show a manifest as comment. Unreadable. Moreover there is not any reason to ask for a manifest.

Comment: Need to add Read uri permission in your manifest file and these permission work for below android 10 ,

Comment: @Laxmi kant. Please stop giving wrong advises. SAF does not need any permission or stuff in manifest.

Comment: and one thing is more use ActivityLauncher andoid 10 or above

Comment: <intent-filter>-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
          <category android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" />-->
       </intent-filter>-->

@Laxmikant i did this earlier 
did you mean this

Comment: @blackapps do you have any fix for it , i need it.

Comment: Maybe the issue is exactly that: there is no app installed to support this.
Seems you have already put some tools in your app to return issues. So you could check if FILE is installed when the app can't find any app, then return this info as part of the logs. Obviously it'll not fix your issue but I least you'll have a better understanding of it.

Comment: @blackapps Please be nice, everybody here is trying to help. ❤️

Comment: Thanks @Eselfar for taking a look
Actually there is some file app there in the device
But you actually want to say to install some files app in the device like google files or something , Right?

Comment: You have access to the device? I thought you knew about the error because of some user's report.

Comment: @Eselfar yes i have the access to device. Can you please elaborate your  first comment?